# Do items left on the ground in the wilderness stay there overnight?

Tags: die2nite

I have too many items to carry home; what should I do?  Nobody in town is able to help me carry it back.  I don't have enough AP and food/water to make the round trip.  And nighttime is falling really soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, items left on the ground remain there until picked up, or the game ends.

Comment: Make sure you ask on your town forums about how to indicate the location of the items you leave behind.  Most towns will have a map application or a forum thread to indicate the position of important items that are left on the ground.